# iPython magic for Zipline cannot find data bundle

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, zipline

I have a Python 2.7 script that runs Zipline fine on the command prompt, using `--bundle=myBundle` to load the custom data bundle `myBundle` which I have registered using `extension.py`.

```
zipline run -f myAlgo.py --bundle=myBundle --start 2016-6-1 --end 2016-7-1 --data-frequency=minute
```

**Problem:** However when I try to use the `%zipline` IPython magic to run the algorithm, the bundle argument `--bundle` seems to have difficulty finding `myBundle`.

```
%zipline --bundle=myBundle--start 2016-6-1 --end 2016-7-1 --data-frequency=minute
```

Running this will give the error

```
UnknownBundle: No bundle registered with the name u'myBundle'
```

Do we have to register the bundle differently when using IPython notebook?

Answer (score 1):

It is a known (now closed) bug in zipline, see also https://github.com/quantopian/zipline/issues/1542.

As a workaround you can load the following in the cell before the zipline magic:

```
import os

from zipline.utils.run_algo import load_extensions

load_extensions(
    default=True,
    extensions=[],
    strict=True,
    environ=os.environ,
)
```