# Ingesting data into zipline

Tags: python, python-3.x, zipline

I want to use Zipline, but Zipline does not financial data that I need.
Now to make my my own data bundle I went through the following link:
http://www.zipline.io/bundles.html

From what I understood I passed the following command on my ubuntu terminal:

```
"zipline ingest -b /home/furqan/Desktop/python_data"
```

My data is saved in folder 'python_data' located on desktop.
Passing the above command I got into following error:

```
Error: No bundle registered with the name'/home/furqan/Desktop/python_data'`
```

How should I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

To ingest custom data from csv files, you should follow the instructions [here](http://www.zipline.io/bundles.html#ingesting-data-from-csv-files).

You can register your own bundle by editing your extension.py file, and then ingest data to this custom bundle. Also, you can use the csvdir bundle provided by zipline.

First make sure that your data is in correct OHLCV format as their tutorial shows. Then in your path for data `/home/furqan/Desktop/python_data`, create two folders, `minute` and `daily`, and place your data files in the folders seperately according to frequency (if you are only using minute or daily frequency data, just create one folder). One file per asset, and the file name should be the name of asset.

Finally, run the ingest command from terminal:

```
$ CSVDIR=/home/furqan/Desktop/python_data zipline ingest -b your-bundle-name
```

where the parameter for -b is your bundle name. For example, if you are using csvdir bundle, it should be `-b csvdir`.

Answer (score 0):

As said at [iPython magic for Zipline cannot find data bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076616/ipython-magic-for-zipline-cannot-find-data-bundle), it is a known bug in zipline. It says to load zipline as shown below before you do anything else with it. import os

```
from zipline.utils.run_algo import load_extensions

load_extensions(
    default=True,
    extensions=[],
    strict=True,
    environ=os.environ,
)
```

Comment: I need to pass the above commands in terminal before passing ingest command?

Comment: Are you using python?

Comment: Yes I am using python.